# Django Google App Engine Upload files greater than 32mb

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-storage

I have a Django Rest Framework Project that I've integrated with Django-Storages to upload files to GCS. Everything works locally. However, Google App Engine imposes a hard limit of 32mb on the size of each request, I cannot upload any files greater than this described limit.

I looked into many posts here on StackOverflow and on the internet. Some of the solutions out listed the use of Blobstore API. However, I cannot find a way to integrate this into Django. Another solution describes the use of django-filetransfers but that plugin is obsolete.

I would appreciate it if someone can point me towards an approach I can take to fixing this problem.

PS: I would like to point out that the current setup works likes this. A post request sends the file up to the server which then handles the process of storing the file in google cloud storage. Since Google App Engine restricts request size to 32mb I cannot get to the point of receiving the file. So my issue is that how can I go about uploading these large files.

Answer (score 0):

According with the official documentation[1] cloud storage can manage files until the 5 tb of size, nevertheless, is recommended take a look at the best practices document[2], also there is an example about how to upload objects using python here [3].

[1]https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert
[2]https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#uploading
[3]https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would like to point out that the current setup works likes this. A post request sends the file up to the server which then handles the process of storing the file in google cloud storage. Since Google App Engine restricts request size to 32mb I cannot get past the point the first step. So my issue is with Google App Engine and not Google Cloud Storage. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: According with the official documentation 32 Mb is the limit for handling requests on app engine, therefore https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Requests, you could make your requests directly to Cloud Storage, as is explained on this example https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage